# No support for Java 7 in Drools  ("RuntimeDroolsException: value '1.7' is not a valid language level")

Tags: java, drools, java-7, rule-engine

While I'm moving my project to java7, Drools starting throwing RuntimeDroolsException exception during init process. When i dig further, I found that this is happening when it validates java dialect.

The problem is: Drools 5.1.1 compares "java.version" system property with LANGUAGE_LEVELS to validate it. LANGUAGE_LEVELS is hard-coded list of java versions till 1.6

```
In org.drools.rule.builder.dialect.java.JavaDialectConfiguration,
public static final String[]        LANGUAGE_LEVELS = new String[]{"1.5", "1.6"};
```

I didn't want to change the source code. So I added the below as a workaround to bypass java dialect validation.

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.setProperty( "drools.dialect.java.compiler.lnglevel","1.6" );
PackageBuilderConfiguration cfg =
new PackageBuilderConfiguration( properties );
KnowledgeBuilder knowledgeBuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(cfg);
```

Is there any better way of doing this other than editing source code?

P.S: Drools 5.1.1 is the latest production version of the drools

Comment: Drools 5.2.0. Final is the latest product version or the drools. (http://www.jboss.org/drools/downloads)

Comment: i just ran into this exact same issue (and no, i cannot upgrade drools for reasons that are beyond my control) - does this workaround work ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in 5.2.1.FINAL version

https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBRULES-3163

Answer (score 6):

When you still want to use `Drools 5.1.1` (switching to a higher version is not always easy because rules do not compile anymore), this might be another, non-programmatic workaround.

In `META-INF/drools.packagebuilder.conf` you can add these properties:

```
 drools.dialect.java.compiler = ECLIPSE 
 drools.dialect.java.lngLevel = 1.6 
 drools.dialect.java.compiler.lnglevel = 1.6
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the above problem by replacing my referenced drools-complier.jar with the 5.4.0.Final version.  I tried earlier releases of this jar but the same error resulted.  This updated jar can be downloaded from the [drools maven repo](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.drools/drools-compiler/5.4.0.Final)

Answer (score -2):

The best way would be submitting a patch to the project itself and helping them support Java 7 as well and then upgrading to that version once it is available.

Comment: That fine but, i think that extending the array might be not enough.

Comment: This answer is incredibly obsolete by now, and was in my opinion not really a good answer to begin with.